# Build Tensorflow Demo For Android

Tags: android, tensorflow, bazel, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am following this link to build the Android App:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/README.md

I am using Window Subsystem Linux command to do this project.

I have installed Bazel already.

I know that after I install Bazel, and before I run the build command, I need to change the WORKSPACE file with correct NDK/ADK file address and go to the workspace root and run "touch WORKSPACE". Here are the codes i ran:

```
'tensorflow folder sits inside 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\lxss\home\alexluk\tensorflow
cd /home/username/tensorflow     

touch WORKSPACE
```

However, when i ran "touch WORKSPACE", here is the error i got:

```
touch: cannont touch 'WORKSPACE': onput/output error
```

It would be great if anyone can let me know where went wrong and what should I do.

Comment: I think the file disappeared as this post suggested: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/659) and i verified WORKSPACE file is actually missing by running "ls -a" in the root folder. However still couldn't find a solution

Comment: check this https://blog.mindorks.com/android-tensorflow-machine-learning-example-ff0e9b2654cc#.vqpvvyber if it helps.

Comment: Yes, it works after I reinstall tensorflow, thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future people that might need help with this:

It looks like Windows Subsystem Linux is very particular about not editing the Linux files from Windows.  See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/):

> DO NOT, *under ANY circumstances*, create and/or modify Linux files using Windows apps, tools, scripts, consoles, etc.

At this point, you can probably remove the file using Windows and then recreate it using Linux.

Comment: I agree. However I turned to use Virtual Machine altogether because using Windows Subsystem Linux is quite problematic for this particular purpose (building tensorflow project on Android)